# Dealock in Java Help in interpretation of Jstack in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, deadlock

I have a java deadlock seems like a problem with groovy. Need suggestions.

Found one Java-level deadlock

```
"http-26100-Processor20":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007fc22f725b70 (object 0x00007fc248a51a58, a java.lang.Object),
  which is held by "MEC"

"MEC":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x000000000358e2e8 (object 0x00007fc248aed588, a java.beans.PropertyDescriptor),
  which is held by "IOC"

"IOC":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007fc22f725b70 (object 0x00007fc248a51a58, a java.lang.Object),
  which is held by "MEC"


Java stack information for the threads listed above


"http-26100-Processor20":
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:157)
    - waiting to lock <0x00007fc248a51a58> (a java.lang.Object)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:2940)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:2938)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:2921)
    - locked <0x00007fc42e5e48a0> (a groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.initialize(ExpandoMetaClass.java:463)
    - locked <0x00007fc42e5e48a0> (a groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.createClassMetaClassGetPropertySite(AbstractCallSite.java:304)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.createGetPropertySite(AbstractCallSite.java:256)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.acceptGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:243)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ReflectionUtils.getConfigProperty(ReflectionUtils.groovy:34)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils.isAjax(SpringSecurityUtils.java:296)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint.determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.buildRedirectUrlToLoginPage(LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.java:151)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence(LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.java:141)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.IpAddressFilter.doFilter(IpAddressFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:874)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"MEC":
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.getReadMethod(PropertyDescriptor.java:158)
    - waiting to lock <0x00007fc248aed588> (a java.beans.PropertyDescriptor)
    at java.beans.Introspector.processPropertyDescriptors(Introspector.java:683)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetPropertyInfo(Introspector.java:615)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:407)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:164)
    - locked <0x00007fc248a51a58> (a java.lang.Object)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:2940)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:2938)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:2921)
    - locked <0x00007fc42e910328> (a groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.initialize(ExpandoMetaClass.java:463)
    - locked <0x00007fc42e910328> (a groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:751)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.(GroovyObjectSupport.java:32)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.(Closure.java:100)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.(Script1.groovy)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at Script1$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at Script1$run.call(Unknown Source)


"IOC":
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1277)
    - waiting to lock <0x00007fc248a51a58> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.beans.Introspector.internalFindMethod(Introspector.java:1312)
    at java.beans.Introspector.findMethod(Introspector.java:1383)
    at java.beans.Introspector.findMethod(Introspector.java:1363)
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.getReadMethod(PropertyDescriptor.java:179)
    - locked <0x00007fc248aed588> (a java.beans.PropertyDescriptor)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.applyPropertyDescriptors(MetaClassImpl.java:2215)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setupProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:1995)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:2950)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:2921)
    - locked <0x00007fc42e6276d0> (a groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.initialize(ExpandoMetaClass.java:463)
    - locked <0x00007fc42e6276d0> (a groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:751)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.(GroovyObjectSupport.java:32)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.(Closure.java:100)
```

Comment: "Hi, my car definitely has a broken transmission. How do I fix it?". In other words: show us your code (and as little of it as possible)...

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Groovy with code that is beyond our control (a lock acquired by BeanInfo). This happens, in general, under heavy load on application startup. Can you give us more information about the context where this happens?